# MTOM attachment encoded twice in SOAP payload

Tags: web-services, soap, jax-ws, soapui, mtom

I am sure this is just pilot error, but cannot find a solution.  Have a jax-ws web service with a soap payload operation that includes an attachment.  Here is a snippet of the schema doc.  This is the type defined:

```
    <xs:complexType name="BinaryAttachmentType">
           <xs:simpleContent>
              <xs:restriction base="xmime:base64Binary">
                <xs:attribute ref="xmime:contentType" use="required" />
              </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
```

Embedded  in this element definition:

```
<xs:element name="Contact">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <!-- removed other elements -->
           <xs:element name="Attachment" type="BinaryAttachmentType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element
```

Using soapUI, SOAP looks like:

```
<hsn:Contact>
    <!-- other elements -->
        <hsn:Attachment xm:contentType="image/jpeg">cid:323665198529</hsn:Attachment>
</hsn:Contact>
```

Attached file in soapUI:
[image]
When I look at http from log:

http Header:

```
 "Content-Type: multipart/related; type="text/xml"; start="<rootpart@soapui.org>"; boundary="----=_Part_15_23791896.1485382707426""
 "SOAPAction: "http://hsn.us.banner.hsntech.com/Level1Request""
 "MIME-Version: 1.0"
 "Content-Length: 104164"
 "Host: localhost:7001"
 "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)"
 "------=_Part_15_23791896.1485382707426"
 "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8"
 "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit"
 "Content-ID: <rootpart@soapui.org>"
```

in SOAP body, see attachment element with base64-encoded file:

```
<hsn:AttachmentFileName>test1.jpg</hsn:AttachmentFileName>
        <hsn:Attachment xm:contentType="image/jpeg">/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD .. rest of base64 encoding
```

then after SOAP message, encoded attachment again:

```
------=_Part_15_23791896.1485382707426
  Content-Type: image/jpeg; 
  name=Foo.jpg
  Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
  Content-ID: <Foo.jpg>
  Content-Disposition: attachment; name=Foo.jpg; filename=Foo.jpg

  (... encoded attachment again )
 [0xff][0xd8][0xff][0xe0][0x0][0x10]JFIF[0x0][0x1][0x1][0x1][0x0]`[0x0]`[0x0][0x0][0xff][0xdb][0x0]C[0x0][\n]
```

So, why the file encoded twice in the request?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that **Enable MTOM** is set to **True** in the Request Properties:

[image: Request Properties]